# German equivalent for "the basis of something"

Tags: phrase

I couldn't realize what could be the proper German translation of that pattern. If I use it like below, makes it any sense?

> The basis of the specific grammar
>   Die Grundlage der spezifischen Grammatik

Comment: Yes, *the basis of* can be translated as *die Grundlage von*. So yes, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: In this sentence _Grundlage_ is fine, but generally, _basis_ has different meanings. Translate the German translations of _basis_ back to English and you'll see what I mean: http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/basis.html

Answer (score 6):

The sentence you wrote is completely correct.

However, you wouldn’t say “spezifische Grammatik”, you would use a specifying article (*diese Grammatik* / *dieser Grammatik* in your case).

More possible translation include:
"Basis" would be for example the base of a triangle,
"Fundament" - the base of a building
"Sockel" - the thing a statue is placed on

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Comment: How do I type typographic apostrophes on a German keyboard?

Comment: You can do Alt+0146 on Windows, or Alt gr + shift + n on some Linux distributions.

Comment: @gizmo maybe after you see the rest of my example you'll count on me, actually there was generalization, the rest of my case was: "Which of the following defines the basis of the specific grammar of all possible human languages."

Comment: @Bergmann One very rare example for a nice use of "spezifisch" - Congrats

Answer (score 1):

- die Grundlage
- die Basis
- das Fundament
- die Wurzeln

sind alles mögliche Übersetzungen für 'the basis'.